# Module and Manipulate: Why the Red Highlighting?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, syntax-highlighting

If I define a function that returns a `Manipulate` object, and the `Manipulate` has a local variable inside of it, the local variable is highlighted in red. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
MyTrigDemo[f_] := Module[{plot},
plot[A_] := 
Plot[A Sin[2 \[Pi] f x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}];
Manipulate[plot[A], {A, 0, 2}]
]
```

displays as (v10.0.0.0)

[image]

Despite the scary highlighting, the function seems to work as I expect. Is this structure inadvisable for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ):

> **Module variables should *never* appear inside `Dynamic`s or `Manipulate`s internal to that `Module`.**
>
> ...
>
> In fact, this rule is so straightforward and universal, there's no reason that 
>   we shouldn't have some advisory syntax highlighting which points out the 
>   badness...I intend to do this for a future release.

See also here in the documentation for *why* doing this is a bad idea: [Module vs DynamicModule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#877365235).

In short, `Module` variables are meant to cease existing as soon as that `Module` exits, but `Manipulate` would try to continue using them.