# Extrema of a function of three variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, vector-calculus

To identify and classify the critical points of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^3+xz^2-3x^2+y^2+2z^2$, I used the Hessian matrix method.

```
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2;
cpts = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y, z}] == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

This gave me the critical points $(0,0,0)$ and $(2,0,0)$. Then I calculate the Hessian.

```
H = D[f, {{x, y, z}, 2}];
MatrixForm[H]
```

Which gave me:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-6+6x & 0 & 2z\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
2z & 0 & 4+2z
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I calculated:

```
Det[H /. {x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 0}]
```

Which was 96. Since this is positive, the Hessian method tells me that I must have a local minimum, maximum, or saddle point. Then I did this:

```
MatrixForm[H /. {x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 0}]
```

Which gave me:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the sequence of principal minors is:

$$ 6, \qquad \begin{vmatrix}6 & 0\\0 & 2\end{vmatrix}=12,\qquad\text{and}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}6 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 8\end{bmatrix}=96$$

Because they are all positive, we have a local minimum at (2,0,0). A similar test reveals a saddle point at (0,0,0).

**My Question:** I am now wondering how I might go about doing something in Mathematica to check that I do indeed have a local minimum, giving me some confidence in this method. Maybe something on the saddle point as well? I can't visualize due to the added dimension, but perhaps folks have some other ideas?

**Notebook Share:** This [notebook](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/StewartMathematica/chapter14/section14_7part4.nb) will give you an idea of what I've written for my students thus far.

**FindMinimum and FindMaximum Weird Result?**

Trying belisarius and OleksandrR suggestion, I think I am looking at a very strange result:

```
In[12]:= FindMinimum[{f, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, {x, 2}, {y, 
  0}, {z, 0}]

Out[12]= {-4., {x -> 2., y -> 0., z -> 0.}}

In[14]:= FindMaximum[{f, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, {x, 2}, {y, 
  0}, {z, 0}]

Out[14]= {-4., {x -> 2., y -> 0., z -> 0.}}
```

Any thoughts or explanation on these results?

**Michael E2 Comment Suggestion:**

Since I am writing notebooks that have many pages, examples, and sometimes 2, 3, 4, or 5 Manipulate GUIs, I have to protect the content. So here is my adjustment to MichaelE2's wonderful example:

```
DynamicModule[{f, x, y, z, cpts},
 f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2;
 cpts = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[Grad[f, {x, y, z}] == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals];
 Manipulate[
  With[{f0 = f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> cp]}, 
   Show[ContourPlot3D[
     f == f0 + level, {x, cp[[1]] - 10^eps, cp[[1]] + 10^eps}, {y, 
      cp[[2]] - 10^eps, cp[[2]] + 10^eps}, {z, cp[[3]] - 10^eps, 
      cp[[3]] + 10^eps}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotPoints -> ControlActive[9, 25],
     ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Pane[Row[{"f \[Equal]", f0, 
         Sign[level] /. {-1 -> "-", 0 | 1 -> "+"}, Abs@level}, " "], 
       100]],
    Graphics3D[{
      Red, Sphere[cp, .04]
      }]
    ]],
  {{level, 0.}, -1., 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{eps, 0., "zoom"}, -1, Log10[2.], Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {cp, cpts}]]
```

Adding `ContourStyle->Opacity[0.7]` and `Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[cp, .04]}]` also shows the critical point.

[image]

Comment: `NMinimize[f, {x, y, z}]` finds your local minima

Comment: @belisarius `FindMinimum` is a better option for local minimization. Here you just happen to be lucky that `NMinimize` fails to find the global minimum.

Comment: @belisarius Check out the edit to my original post under **FindMinimum and FindMaximum Weird Result?**

Comment: @David I wasn't the one who suggested `FindMinimum` :D

Comment: @David Re "Weird Result" -- The gradient is zero at the starting point, isn't it?  It won't take a step. Try bumping the starting value by a small amount.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Worked. I tried `FindMaximum[{f, (x - 2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, {x, 2.2}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}]` and got a different answer: `{-2.84217*10^-14, {x -> 3., y -> 0., z -> 0.}}`. Which raises another good question: If you are working with a function of say three or four variables, how do folks decide what guesses to enter in FindMinimum and FindMaximum?

Comment: Comments are not really meant for open-ended discussions, but for polynomial `f`, theoretically `NSolve[D[f, {x,y,z} == {0,0,0}], {x,y,z}]` will give you all the critical points. In general, it's a notoriously difficult. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hundred-DollarHundred-DigitChallengeProblems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to teach the students to interpret level sets, then it is possible visualize the behavior of a function by manipulating the level.  There are various ways to set it up, to cue the students' recognition of the type of extremum, etc. Here's one, whipped up rather quickly.

```
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f = x^3 + x z^2 - 3 x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2
cpts = {x, y, z} /. Solve[Grad[f, {x, y, z}] == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals];
Manipulate[
 With[{f0 = f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> cp]},
  ContourPlot3D[f == f0 + level,
   {x, cp[[1]] - 10^eps, cp[[1]] + 10^eps},
   {y, cp[[2]] - 10^eps, cp[[2]] + 10^eps},
   {z, cp[[3]] - 10^eps, cp[[3]] + 10^eps},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> ControlActive[9, 25],
   PlotLabel -> 
    Pane[Row[{"f \[Equal]", f0, Sign[level] /. {-1 -> "-", 0 | 1 -> "+"}, 
      Abs@level}, " "], 100]
   ]],
 {{level, 0.}, -1., 1.},
 {{eps, 0., "zoom"}, -1, Log10[2.]},
 {cp, cpts}]
```

Example: This a typical picture of a saddle point.  Move the `level` slider both left and right to see that `f` has values both less and greater than `0`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example: `f` has a value greater than `-4`, so `-4` is not a local maximum.  Move the `level` to set it to a negative value to see that value below `-4` is not possible (well, within the certainty of such numerical evidence).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As usual, extremely helpful. Couple questions: 1) Is `Contours->{{0}}` needed? 2) In the Row command, what is the purpose of the `"  "` at the end?  3) Why is the Pane command needed?  4) `ControlActive[9,25}` does what? Plot 9 points when dragging a slider, than 25 when you let go?

Comment: As usual, if later in my notebook, I type `Clear[f]` or `x=12`, this Manipulate is ruined, so I've done the typical thing we've talked about  in the past to make an adjustment. See my original post. What do you think?

Comment: @David 1) You're right. I was playing with two different forms and forgot to remove it. 2) Look up `Row`; the 2nd arg is riffled between the row elements. 3) `Pane` keeps the label the same size so the it doesn't jump around when the number of digits change. 4) Look up `ControlActive`; it's for speed when the control is moved, ***and*** odd so that a sample point lies inside the ellipsoid-like figure at an extrema and the level is small and of the right sign (positive for `{2,0,0}` in the example).

Comment: @David  Looks good; global variables such as `f` etc. always present such pitfalls; localizing them is right approach and especially important when handing demonstrations off to independent humans to use (such as students).  You might also be interested in this issue, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90013/does-contourplot3d-leak-assignments-inside-manipulate, which came up while I played with your problem.

Comment: If you don't have the time, please ignore this request. If you do, do you think you could add an update to this block of code based on your current work on [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/does-dynamicmodule-cure-problem-with-manipulate/90075#90075](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/does-dynamicmodule-cure-problem-with-manipulate/90075#90075) ? It would be another great example to look at.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure what to do, nor what you think can be done.  In this case, the contour plot must be recomputed whenever the `level` or the critical point changes.  I did think about speed here, and that's why I added `PlotPoints -> ControlActive[9, 25]`: I think it's the fastest way to get sufficient quality.  (You can bump the `9` down to `7` or `5`, but you don't gain much or lose much, as I recall.)  Is there something you see that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 6):

another test:

```
f = x^3 + x*z^2 - 3*x^2 + y^2 + 2*z^2; 
cpts = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y, z}] == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]

{{x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 0}}

hesse = D[f, {{x, y, z}, 2}] /. cpts

{{{-6, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}, {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 8}}}

{ev1[l1,l2,l3], ev2[l1,l2,l3]} = Eigenvalues /@ hesse

{{-6, 4, 2}, {8, 6, 2}}
```

all eigenvalues positive ->  local minimum

all eigenvalues negative -> local maximum

eigenvalues l1,l2,l3 with l1*l2*l3 < 0  -> saddlepoint

**Completion**

a further test

hesse matrix positive definit -> local minimum

hesse matrix negative definit -> local maximum

with Davids function:

```
f = x^3 + x*z^2 - 3*x^2 + y^2 + 2*z^2; 
cpts = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y, z}] == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
hesse = D[f, {{x, y, z}, 2}] /. cpts; 

{{x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 0}}

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hesse
NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hesse

{False, True}

{False, False}
```

-> first point = saddel, second point = local minimum

another function:

```
g = x^4 - y^4; 
pts = Solve[Grad[g, {x, y}] == 0, {x, y}]
h = D[g, {{x, y}, 2}] /. pts

{{x -> 0, y -> 0}}

{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ h
NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ /@ h

{False}

{False}
```

a saddle point

```
Plot3D[g, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot3D]

As an example, you can show your result:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^3 + x*z^2 - 3*x^2 + y^2 + 2*z^2; 

Show[Plot3D[f[x, y, 0], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 & }], DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y, 0], 
     {x, {0, 2}}, {y, {0, 0}}, PlotStyle -> 
       Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image: plot3d2]

Comment: Yes, I did a little reading on positive and negative definite matrices, but these two tests and my test are the type of things that need rigorous abstract proofs in advanced classes. My question really wants to focus on whether there is any visual or numerical experimentation that can be done to verify that the answers given by my Hessian test are correct.

Comment: "any visual … experimentation that can be done to verify that the answers given by my Hessian test are correct" - the quick visual test is to plot the quadratic form generated by truncating the Taylor expansion up to the Hessian term. A hyperbolic paraboloid means the point of the original function was a saddle; an elliptic paraboloid opening in the appropriate direction is what you'll get for an optimum.

Comment: @J.M. This could be something special I should learn. Perhaps you could do a detailed answer showing these results? Also, maybe you could point me toward some reading on this idea?

Comment: I don't think I need to, @David. Look at Willinski's last figure, where he embedded contours in the surface to assist with the visualization. Note the hyperbola-like curves around the saddle and the ellipse-like curves around the optimum. There's your visual cue. :)

Comment: @Willinski. Thanks for that last image. I believe it very helpful. My assumption is that you assumed that the z-value of the critical point was zero, then searched for the x and y values.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualise a function of 3 paramters by putting one of them as argument of Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[f /. z -> z1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], {z1, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: And how can I use this to demonstrate a local minimum at (2,0,0) and a saddle point at (0,0,0)?